# Criar página de perfil de acordo com o usuário

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, login

Quero fazer com que cada usuário cadastrado no meu site tenha sua própria página de perfil, em que todos usuários poderão acessá-la e ver as informações, como nome, e-mail, data de nascimento, etc.. Porém, não sei 2 coisas:

1ª: Como consigo fazer com que eu consiga mostrar as informações presentes na tabela do banco de dados MySQL? Já consegui apenas o e-mail, mas como sou iniciante não sei exatamente como mostrar com o resto das informações

2º: Essa é a minha maior dúvida. Como crio uma página para cada usuário? Já vi que ela não precisa ser exatamente "física" e sim virtual. Mas não sei como faço.

connect.inc (faz o link para o banco de dados)

```
<?php
$dbservername = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword= '';
$dbdatabase = 'usuarios';

    $connect = mysqli_connect ($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {


    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

include "connect.inc";
session_start ();

if (isset ($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST ['senha']);

    $sel_user = "select id from cadastro where email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query ($connect, $sel_user);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row ['active'];

    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

    if ($check_user == 1 )  {

        $_SESSION ['login_user'] = $email;

        header ("location: capa.php");
    }

    else {

        echo "Email or password is not correct, try again’";

    }


}

?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
include ("connect.inc");
session_start ();
$user_check = $_SESSION ['login_user'];
  $ses_sql = mysqli_query($connect,"select email from cadastro where email = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['email'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.html");
   }
?>
```

Comment: Adicione um addslashes em seu post para evitar sql injection. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Iria responder na outra pergunta, mas você apagou a mesma, então vou só dar uma explicada rápida. Você primeiramente precisa ter um parâmetro na URL indicando qual usuário você irá exibir o perfil, exemplo: `perfil.php?usuario=3`, nesse caso vou pegar o perfil do usuário 3, daí é só realizar uma consulta em sua tabela assim: `select * from cadastro where id= '3'`, sua consulta retornará um array com todos dados do usuário daquele perfil, a partir daí é só exibir os dados do mesmo na página.

Comment: Entendi. Como coloco o parâmetro na URL? Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @lvcs eu votei pra reabrir, se você votar e mais 3 ai você responde normalmente

Comment: @AlexandreSchleder apenas acessando ou colocando links indo para URLS por exemplo: `meusite.com/perfil.php?usuario=3` ou usando URL amigáveis pode ter algo como `meusite.com/perfil/3`

Comment: @diegofm não acho a pergunta apropriada, na minha visão é ampla, pois tem diversas maneiras de se fazer, e ainda assim não acho que esteja bem explicada, ia responder enquanto estava aberta pra ajudar. Mas ia votar para fechar logo depois.

Comment: Eu não procuro uma solução específica. Queria apenas que me falassem alguma forma possível de se fazer. Sendo iniciante, eu não consigo ser mais específico do que isso, aí fica difícil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo básico sem usar banco de dados para que qualquer membro possa tirar algo de bom:

```
<?php

$usuarios = [
    1 => ['nome' => 'Josue Ramos',      'idade' => 54,  'ocupacao' => 'ambulante' ],
    3 => ['nome' => 'Leonardo V.',      'idade' => 20,  'ocupacao' => 'desenvolvedor' ],
    4 => ['nome' => 'Patricia S.',      'idade' => 20,  'ocupacao' => 'quimica' ],
    5 => ['nome' => 'Figaldo M.' ,      'idade' => 34,  'ocupacao' => 'medico' ],
    7 => ['nome' => 'Ana Maria'  ,      'idade' => 45,  'ocupacao' => 'cozinheira' ],
];

if( isset($_GET['usuario']) ) {
    $usuario_id = (int)$_GET['usuario'];

    // faria aqui o: SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $usuario_id 

    if( array_key_exists($usuario_id, $usuarios) )  // no meu caso esse seria meu   SELECT
        $usuario = $usuarios[$usuario_id];
    else
        die('Usuario nao encontrado');
}
else
    die('Usuario nao encontrado');

?>

<h2>Perfil de '<?php echo $usuario['nome'] ?>'</h2>

<p>Tem <?php echo $usuario['idade'] ?> anos de idade.</p>

<p>Ocupa o cargo de <?php echo $usuario['ocupacao'] ?>.</p>
```

---

### Explicação

Nesse exemplo tenho um `array` de usuários que simula uma tabela do banco de dados, ao acessar a página será necessário a informação de um identificador único para o usuário, como por exemplo temos aqui:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23036/lvcs
```

Onde `23036` é meu identificador de usuário.

Ao acessar a página, precisamos pegar esse identificador que nos foi passado e exibir informações do usuário pertencente ao mesmo, nessa parte eu pego o `$_GET['usuario']` e faço uma consulta no meu `array`, que no meu caso simula o banco de dados, caso exista esse usuário, gravo ele em uma variável par realizar a exibição, caso não exista, mato a página com uma mensagem qualquer de erro.

---

### Adaptar para banco de dados

Para pegar o usuário a partir de um banco de dados e não de uma lista segue esses passos:

- Apagar lista `$usuarios`.
- Fazer conexão com banco de dados.
- Realizar consulta na tabela de usuários onde o identificador seja igual ao da URL.
- Verificar se houve um resultado verdadeiro.
- Armazenar na variável `$usuario`.

Deixando o código mais ou menos assim (usando `mysqli_*`):

```
if( isset($_GET['usuario']) ) {
    $usuario_id = (int)$_GET['usuario'];
    $usaurio = null;

    // faria aqui o: SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $usuario_id 

    $connect = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lrv_001');
    $sel_user = "select * from users where id = '$usuario_id'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query ($connect, $sel_user);
    $usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if($row == $usuario)
        die('Usuario nao encontrado');
}
else
    die('Usuario nao encontrado');
```

- Pesquise por `bind`, para torna o sistema mais seguro. Não usei aqui porque estou sem tempo.

---

### Observações

- Para 'coloca parâmetro na URL', como você perguntou nos comentários, vai depender muito do contexto do seu sistema, normalmente é junto com a listagem de usuários, você coloca o link da página do perfil + o identificador do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui fazer a página de perfil já, usando o 2º método com o banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte, tu conheces o método GET? sim? perfeito, o que você vai fazer é o seguinte, você vai criar uma página com o nome perfil.php, OK!. Logo depois você vai fazer uma query nesse perfil, exemplo, mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = 2");  e logo depois você pega um fetch_array() para exibir todos os dados desse usuário. Tá mas por que o método get? por que você pode ter milhões de usuarios com milhares de perfis diferentes tento só um arquivo de perfil no seu site. o get vai passar parametros, tipo. www.meusite.io/perfil.php?id=3  <-- esse id é igual a 3 vai mostar o perfil do usuário que tem o id 3 no banco de dados.

Desculpe não falar o passo a passo de como fazer, é por que é uma coisa que tem várias formas de se fazer, então se você é iniciante, aconselho você estudar um pouco de banco de dados e do método get. Depois disso você vai poder fazer a sua página de perfis com tranquilidade.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wyf2ejKRVb0   <-- veja esse vídeo e aprenda o que você quer fazer.